# R Shiny checkboxGroupInput - select all checkboxes by click

Tags: r, shiny

I have a R Shiny app that contains checkboxGroupInput, and I'm trying to create a "select all" button, using updateCheckboxGroupInput function.
You can see the full code below, but basically I defined the cb groups like this:

```
checkboxGroupInput("campaigns","Choose campaign(s):",campaigns_list)
```

and then, on a button click, call the function:

```
updateCheckboxGroupInput(session,"campaigns","Choose campaign(s):",choices=campaigns_list,selected=campaigns_list)
```

I have an indication that the function ran, but what it does is actually UNselecting the checkboxes.
BTW, when I put the selected upon defining the cbGroupInput it did worked, but not on the function.

Thanks!

this is my server.R:

```
library(shiny)
source('usefulFunctions.R')
shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {

  output$cascading <- renderUI({
    provider_id <- input$provider
    if (provider_id == "") return(NULL)
    campaigns_list <<- t(getCampaigns(provider_id))
    tagList(
      checkboxGroupInput("campaigns","Choose campaign(s):", 
                         choices = campaigns_list, selected = campaigns_list),
      actionLink("selectall","Select All")
      )
  })

  observe({
    if(is.null(input$selectall)) return(NULL)
    if (input$selectall > 0)
    {
      print(campaigns_list)
      updateCheckboxGroupInput(session,"campaigns","Choose campaign(s):",choices=campaigns_list,selected=campaigns_list)
    }
    })


})
```

Comment: The `shinyWidgets` library has a nice function called `pickerInput()` that comes with a nice "select all/deselect all" interface for inputs: https://dreamrs.github.io/shinyWidgets/index.html

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I also added the select and unselect options here by checking if the button or link are divisible by 2

```
#rm(list = ls())
library(shiny)
campaigns_list <- letters[1:10]

ui =fluidPage(
  checkboxGroupInput("campaigns","Choose campaign(s):",campaigns_list),
  actionLink("selectall","Select All") 
)
server = function(input, output, session) {

  observe({
    if(input$selectall == 0) return(NULL) 
    else if (input$selectall%%2 == 0)
    {
      updateCheckboxGroupInput(session,"campaigns","Choose campaign(s):",choices=campaigns_list)
    }
    else
    {
      updateCheckboxGroupInput(session,"campaigns","Choose campaign(s):",choices=campaigns_list,selected=campaigns_list)
    }
  })
}
runApp(list(ui = ui, server = server))
```

Answer (score 2):

If `campaigns_list` is a list,  might be because you are specifying the list of all your choices instead of the value of the boxes that should be selected in the `selected` argument of your `updateCheckboxGroupInput`.

Try replacing `selected=campaigns_list` by `selected=unlist(campaigns_list)`.

Here is an example with dummy names:

```
library(shiny)
server<-function(input, output,session) {
  observe({
    if(input$selectall == 0) return(NULL)
    else if (input$selectall > 0)
    {
      variables<-list("Cylinders" = "cyl","Transmission" = "am","Gears" = "gear")
      updateCheckboxGroupInput(session,"variable","Variable:",choices=variables,selected=unlist(variables))
    }
  })
}

ui <- shinyUI(fluidPage(        
    checkboxGroupInput("variable", "Variable:",list("Cylinders" = "cyl","Transmission" = "am","Gears" = "gear")),
    actionButton("selectall", "Select All")
))
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: add an Unselect All button for a complete solution

Comment: use observeEvent instead of observe