# R Shiny how to add 'select all' in checkbox within renderui

Tags: r, checkbox, shiny

I am using renderui in R Shiny to generate a checkbox, I'm wondering how to add a 'select all' option, which can be used to check and uncheck all the boxed.
[here is an example of the checkbox I want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sn4mJ.png)

This [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28829682/r-shiny-checkboxgroupinput-select-all-checkboxes-by-click) shows how to add the 'select all' button, but is not for the checkbox inside renderui. Currently the method I used is

```
  output$trmt_id <- renderUI({

if(is.null(ep_info())) {
  return() 
}

trmt_ids <- unique(ep_info()$TRMT_ID)
# add 'selected = ' to pre-select ctrl
checkboxGroupInput("input_trmt_id", "Choose Treatment ID (Include Control)", choices = c(trmt_ids, 'All'))})


observeEvent(input$input_trmt_id, {
if (input$input_trmt_id %in% 'All') {

  updateCheckboxGroupInput(session, "input_trmt_id", "Choose Treatment ID (Include Control)", choices = c(unique(ep_info()$TRMT_ID), 'all'), selected = unique(ep_info()$TRMT_ID))
}})
```

But the problem of this piece of code is user cannot unselect all boxed just by clicking 'all' again.

Do you have some better ideas? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No checkboxes, but an easy alternative with `pickerInput` :

```
library("shiny")
library("shinyWidgets")

ui <- fluidPage(
  column(
    width = 4,
    pickerInput(
      inputId = "id", label = "Choices :",
      choices = c("Banana", "Blueberry", "Cherry", "Coconut", "Grapefruit",
                  "Kiwi", "Lemon", "Lime", "Mango", "Orange", "Papaya"),
      options = list(`actions-box` = TRUE, `selected-text-format` = "count > 2",
                     `count-selected-text` = "{0}/{1} fruits"),
      multiple = TRUE
    ),
    verbatimTextOutput(outputId = "res")
  )
)


server <- function(input, output) {
  output$res <- renderPrint({
    input$id
  })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Result looks like :

[image]