# How do I include an option in R Shiny app for "all categories" in multiple time series?

Tags: r, ggplot2, shiny, plotly

I included an image for a better idea, but I'm just trying to include an option to include categories in the time series. I.e. rather than just choosing between national, white, black, asian, etc., I'd like to include one for all (i.e. include all categories in a multiple line chart in addition to the single line options), but can't seem to figure out how. At some point I'd also like there to be an option to compare between categories, but I'm still pretty new...will edit this code/question when I figure that one out.

```
    rm(list=ls())

    library(shiny)
    library(shinyWidgets)
    library(ggplot2)
    library(dplyr)
    library(readxl)
    library(scales)
    library(ggthemes)
    library (plotly)

    data<-read_excel("C:/Users/Kanew/OneDrive/Desktop/RApp/Unemployment2.xlsx")
    data$Date<-as.Date(data$MonthYear)

    ui <- fluidPage(

        h1("National Unemployment Rate by Race"),

        selectInput(
            inputId = "Category",
            label = "Select Race or National Rate",
            choices = unique(data$Category),
            selected = "National"
        ),

        plotlyOutput("plot"),

        setBackgroundColor("#778899")
    )

    server <- function(input, output, session) {

        output$plot <- renderPlotly({
            data %>%
                filter(Category == input$Category) %>%
                ggplot(data, mapping = aes(x=Date, y = Rate, colour = Category)) +
                geom_line() + 
                xlab("Year") + ylab("Unemployment Rate (%)") +
                scale_y_continuous(breaks=c(0, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14, 16, 18))+
                scale_x_date(date_breaks = "years" , date_labels = "%Y")+
                theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45, hjust = 1))+
                theme_economist() +
                scale_fill_economist()


        })

    }

    shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: When piping data into ggplot, you can remove data parameter : `ggplot( aes(x=Date, y = Rate, colour = Category)) +`

Answer (score 1):

A classic question concerning how to add a "select all/none" option for `checkboxGroupInput()`.  You'll find some [others](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28829682/r-shiny-checkboxgroupinput-select-all-checkboxes-by-click) have added solutions for this before, but that example uses an action link (or action button).  I would prefer personally to use a single `checkboxInput()` to set the "all" or "none" selection criterion.  You would then want to setup an `observeEvent()` to check whenever the status of this checkbox element changes, and when it does, then use `updateCheckboxGroupInput()` to change the `selected=` status of your particular `checkboxGroupInput()` container.

Make sense?

Here's a working example that uses `mtcars`.

```
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

ui <- fluidPage(
    titlePanel("Example of select all"),
    sidebarLayout(
        sidebarPanel(
            
            # this is our group checkbox
            checkboxGroupInput(
                inputId = 'cylinders',
                label = 'Select specific cylinders',
                choices = unique(mtcars$cyl)
            ),

            # this is how we will set the state of "all" or "none"
            checkboxInput('toggle_cyl', 'Select all/none')
        ),
        mainPanel(
           plotOutput("plot")
        )
    )
)
    
server <- function(input, output, session) {
    
    # whenever the status of the toggle changes, check and update the checkbox group input
    observeEvent(input$toggle_cyl, {
        if (input$toggle_cyl)
            updateCheckboxGroupInput(session, 'cylinders', selected = unique(mtcars$cyl))
        else
            updateCheckboxGroupInput(session, 'cylinders', selected = FALSE)
    })
    
    output$plot <- renderPlot({
        mtcars %>%
            dplyr::filter(cyl %in% input$cylinders) %>%
            ggplot(aes(disp, mpg, color=factor(cyl))) +
            geom_point() +
            labs(color='Cyl') +
            theme_bw()
    })
    
}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Given your code, perhaps a check box or other for all because the current construction filters using `==`.

You could use an %in% construct in filter and have it pass multiple selections because selectInput has an option multiple= which defaults to FALSE.  If you set it to TRUE, this should work for most/all of your needs.

Answer (score 0):

Yo can add "All" to the choices :

```
choices = c("All", unique(data$Category)),
```

And change the filter to :

```
filter(Category == input$Category | input$Category == "All" ) %>%
```

Comment: I tried this, but it ends up only showing "all" as an option, then graphs them all in one series. Which is great...not sure why the other categories are removed from the drupdown though.

Comment: It's difficult to help without reproducible example

Comment: Sorry...had trouble getting an image or code in here...I highlighted what changed and what the result was https://i.imgur.com/O7BHYK3.jpg