# How to make shinyWidget materialSwitch update checkboxGroupButtons

Tags: r, shiny, shinywidgets

I want to use a `shinyWidgets` materialSwitch to select all / deselect all when switched, in an adjacent set of checkboxGroupButtons. But in my code below, the switch has no effect on the check boxes:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyWidgets)

ui <- fluidPage(
  checkboxGroupButtons(
    inputId = "somevalue",
    choices = c("A", "B", "C"),
    label = "My label"
  ),
  
  verbatimTextOutput(outputId = "res"),
  
  materialSwitch(
    inputId = "clear",
    label = "Select all?",
    value = TRUE, 
    status = "info"
  )

)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  output$res <- renderPrint({
    input$somevalue
  })
  
  observeEvent(input$clear, {

    if (input$clear) {
      updateCheckboxGroupInput(session, "somevalue", selected = c("A", "B", "C"))
    } else {
      updateCheckboxGroupInput(session = session, inputId = "somevalue", selected = character(0))
    }

  })  

}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

I think the problem is in the if statement as if I skip that I can get the check box group to update, either selecting all or deselecting all every time it's hit. I've also tried using `observe` instead of `observeEvent` [as suggested here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28829682/r-shiny-checkboxgroupinput-select-all-checkboxes-by-click) but to no effect.

Can anyone put me right?

Answer (score 0):

With `checkboxGroupButtons` you should use `updateCheckboxGroupButtons`, and with `checkboxGroupInput` you can use `updateCheckboxGroupInput`.  Both of them work.  Try this

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyWidgets)

ui <- fluidPage(
  checkboxGroupButtons(
  # checkboxGroupInput(
    inputId = "somevalue",
    choices = c("A", "B", "C"), selected = c("A", "B"),
    label = "My label"
  ),
  
  verbatimTextOutput(outputId = "res"),
  
  materialSwitch(
    inputId = "clear",
    label = "Select all?",
    value = TRUE, 
    status = "info"
  )
  
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  output$res <- renderPrint({
    input$somevalue
  })
  
  selection <- eventReactive(input$clear, {
    selected = character(0)
    if (input$clear) {
      selected = c("A", "B", "C")
    } 
    selected
  })
  
  observeEvent(selection(), {
    updateCheckboxGroupButtons(session, 
    # updateCheckboxGroupInput(session, 
                             inputId = "somevalue",
                             choices = c("A", "B", "C"),
                             selected = selection())
  },ignoreNULL = FALSE, ignoreInit = TRUE)  
  
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```